# CakePHP: storing origin URL when redirecting to login page using Permit class

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.4

In `Config/Permit.php` we define rules, which actions are permitted without login. It looks like that:

```
Permit::access(
    array(
        'controller' => array('incentives'), 'action' => array('downloadvoucher')
    ),
    array(),
    array()
);
(...)
Permit::access(
    array('controller' => $controllers),
    array('auth' => true),
    array('redirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'), 'message' => __('Your session has ended. Please log in again.'))
);
```

The redirect is defined at the bottom. What would be the right approach to achieve the following: if the user calls an URL (note: by default in the following format:  base/controller/action/?q=1&q=2#hash ***or*** with routing) he will be redirected to the `users/login` page, but we would like to store somewhere from where he is coming (for example appended to the URL).

I tried this:

```
array('redirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login', '?' => $this->here()), 'message' => __('Your session has ended. Please log in again.'))
```

but of course it doesn't work - the `here()`method is not defined in the Permit class.

Any better ideas?

Comment: Ummm... `Router::url()`? Or what's the deal with the hash in your example URL?

Comment: Why are you using some strange 3rd party lib that doesn't seem to integrate with CakePHPs build in authorization and authentication at all? This looks like you're working around the framework instead of using it.

Comment: I unfortunately can't decide which libs we use... I have to live with that. I already developed a solution with sessions and redirects, which works well. Cheers